# Invalid conversion from int* to int

Tags: c++

I am self studying pointers and would like to know what is the correct way to pass the address?

```
    int main(){
        int kevin = 10,tiu,gana;

        int *kevinpointer;
        kevinpointer = &kevin;

        tiu = kevin;
        gana = &tiu;

        cout << "The value of Kevin is: ";
        cout << kevin << endl;

        cout << "The address of Kevin is: ";
        cout << kevinpointer << endl;

        cout << "The address of KevinPointer is:  ";
        cout << *kevinpointer << endl;

        cout << "The value/address of tiu is: ";
        cout << tiu << endl;

        cout<< "The address of gana is: ";
        cout << gana << endl;

    }
```

I get an error on "gana = &tiu;" > Invalid conversion of int* to int[f-permissive].

Comment: In your snippet `gana` is  an `int`, not pointer to `int`, as such you cannot assign an address `&tiu` to it without triggering warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined variable `gana` as having type `int`

```
    int kevin = 10,tiu,gana;
```

but you are trying to assign an object of type `int *` to it

```
gana = &tiu;
```

If you would define the variable as having type `int *`

```
    int kevin = 10,tiu, *gana;
```

then this statement

```
    gana = &tiu;
```

would be correct.

Take into account that these statements

```
cout << "The address of KevinPointer is:  ";
cout << *kevinpointer << endl;

//...

cout<< "The address of gana is: ";
cout << gana << endl;
```

are wrong. There should be

```
cout << "The address of KevinPointer is:  ";
cout << &kevinpointer << endl;

//...

cout<< "The address of gana is: ";
cout << &gana << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`gana` is an `int`, whereas you're attempting to use it as an `int*`. Change the first two lines to:

```
int kevin = 10, tiu;
int *kevinpointer, *gana;
```

The program should compile. However, you have this snippet:

```
cout<< "The address of gana is: ";
cout << gana << endl;
```

Which doesn't make any sense. The variable `gana` cannot hold its own address. That would require it to be both an `int*` and an `int**` simultaneously, which doesn't make any sense. This code should be:

```
cout << "The address of tiu is: " << gana << endl;
```

Comment: @Josh: oh rly? and `cout<< "The address of gana is: " << gana;` will print out the address of `gana` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. By *everything should work* I meant compile and run. Good catch though, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

pointers are *not* integer. They're not compatible.

In order to force to get integer from pointer, use explicit casting.

```
gana = (int)&tiu;
```

Moreover, standard doesn't say `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *)`. If you want to use the integer type whose size is equal to pointers, you should use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, which is in `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: You should definitely not use a C-style cast.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, Judging from OP's code, he may actually want to use C >o<

Comment: The question is tagged as C++.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, many many beginners make a mistake that doesn't distinguish C and C++, especially they think he's code is C++, even if it uses just little C++ feature (e.g. `cout`) and it's C-style code.